# Double field sent with a comma for SQL Server (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, double, entity-framework-6

I have a table in SQL Server (2012) with the structure Following:
[image]

The representation of the entity in my application (C#):

```
public class Teste
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
}
```

And it was mapped in EF as follows:

```
public class TesteConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Teste>
{
    public TesteConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("vw_Teste");
        HasKey(c => c.Id);
        Property(c => c.Id).HasColumnName("pk_int_IdTeste").HasColumnType("int").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();
        Property(c => c.Description).HasColumnName("str_Descricao").HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(50).IsOptional();
        Property(c => c.Value).HasColumnName("dbl_Valor").HasColumnType("float").IsOptional();
        Property(c => c.Sequence).HasColumnName("int_Sequencial").HasColumnType("int").IsOptional();
    }
}
```

By submitting a new entity to the database is not generated error in EF. But to verify the statement sent by the EF in SQL Server Profiler, it was possible to note the use of commas in the field Double:
[image]

If this statement is executed in SQL Server the following error appears:
[image]

If the comma was replaced by the dot ".", Everything is fine. What can be wrong for the EF submit the statement this way?

Both SQL Server and the application are installed on the same computer, whose culture is set to "pt-BR".

Comment: Rather than post screen prints it will be easier to read if you just copy and paste the SQL and error messages.

Comment: Does the data arrive in your SQL Table? This is probably a glitch in profiler.

Comment: I believe decimal numbers use commas instead of periods for culture pt-BR.  I imagine the profile displays numbers to the user in a format that is consistent with the selected culture.

Comment: @DrKoch, The data is not written in SQL, the table is empty after the update.

Comment: @juharr, Forgive me for the pictures!

Comment: @JasonBoyd, I've changed the culture and region options for en-US, even so the data are not inserted.

Comment: Do you get an error back from EF?  If so what is it?  That would shed more light on the problem than reporting the error you get from SSMS.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the collation of the database and table?

Comment: @JasonBoyd, collation database (Latin1_General_CI_AS), collation table (Latin1_General_CI_AS).

Comment: @JasonBoyd, EF returns no error.